# Sequelize throwing depreciation warning

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize ORM for Node Js.
Everything works fine, the models, the assocaitions, the query part.

But whenever I run my node js application, I receive warnings listed below:

- Not overriding built-in method from model attribute: equals
- [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
- Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: useUTC. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection.

My configuration file:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "",
    "host": "",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "operatorsAliases": false,
    "timezone": "+05:30",
    "dialectOptions": {"useUTC": false}
  },
}
```

I have searched for these warning but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: `Not overriding built-in method from model attribute: equals`, do you by chance have a field set to use the name `equals` in your model? That may be the cause of the error.

Despite what the Sequelize documentation says, you do not need to specify `"operatorsAliases": false` but rather only need to specify, with an array, any aliases you wish to enable.

`useUTC` is not a valid option in Node MySQL. See the [connection options](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options).